# Versioning api endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm working with an API that needs versioning. For now, I'm doing like this:

```
namespace MixApi.UI.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    public class VoController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/vo/order/")]
        public IHttpActionResult Method1() { }
    }
}

namespace MixApi.UI.Controllers.v2
{
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    public class VoController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/vo/order/")]
        public IHttpActionResult Method1() { } // Improved this with new logic

        [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/vo/order2/")]
        public IHttpActionResult Method2() { } // New method for v2
    }
}
```

However, let's say that I'm going to add a new controller, let's say ArticleController. How should I version it? Should it be v1 or v2?

I'm thinking it should be v1, because it's the first version of that controller/endpoint. But then I realize that I'm versioning the controller(the endpoint), and not the API itself. So I get a little bit confused of how I should do the versioning in this case.

How do you guys do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can assign multiple version to a controller and in your case I may consider doing this so if you are on version 2 and come out with a brand new controller you can assign it either one version or both.

```
[Authorize]
[ApiVersion("3.0")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/Users")]
```

I do think that version should be viewed as complete products, so a user will use version 2 as it's the latest (for example) but all of a sudden they must reference version 1 just for a new feature. could cause confusion and doesn't seem to client friendly

Answer (score 1):

It is best to do Versioning on Project Level. There are many versioning guides available which you can follow. I would like to slip in a reference to Semantic Versioning Guidelines here https://semver.org/

This ensures stability of the dependent applications.

> However. Let's say that Im going to add a new controller, let's say ArticleController. How should I version It? Should It be v1 or v2?

You should release the first stable version of your application. And then, follow a versioning process.
So First Stable version would be `v1.0.0` and a revision like adding a controller would be released as `v1.0.1`.
A major change in a module, or section of your app (like code optimization, implementing a new technique etc) should be released as `v1.1.x`

> How do you guys do it?

At my organization, we increment the main version number each year. For example, in 2018 `v2.0.x`, in 2019, `v3.0.x` and so on. For a major module level release, we will increment it from `v2.0.1` to `v2.1.1`. If just a controller was added, we will change it from `v2.1.1` to `v2.1.2`.
You can also refer to releases page for an Open-Source project for reference (an example: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

> I wonder how I shuld do the versioning when adding a new controller/endpoint.

Suppose, you have a major release `v2.x.y` and your API endpoint is `/api/v2/`.
If you add/remove/modify a controller now, you will have a new build with `v2.x.y+1`. In this case your API endpoint will remain the same: `/api/v2/`

Unless it changes from `v2.x.y+1` to `v3.p.q`, your API endpoint should remain the same at `/api/v2/`. Do notice the changes in the Version Numbers.

Comment: but in this case I want the versioning in the URI of my API. That's why I wonder how I shuld do the versioning when adding a new controller/endpoint.

Comment: @Bryan I have edited the answer to include answer to your comment

Comment: Plus one: a controller is an implementation detail. Users shouldn't think about it.

Comment: Just want to point this out, although it might be intentional, but what you're describing is _not_ semantic versioning.  
It says so in your link what it is:
**MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes.** **MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner.** **PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.**
According to this, adding a controller would definitely be a MINOR version, and not a PATCH. Also, you would never increment a version because of a date, so the MAJOR version would never increment if no breaking changes are added.